# Dates not printing using BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm using `biblatex` to process the bibliography for my dissertation using APA. The problem is that dates are not being printed; the dates are being replaced by `a n.d.` and this is not correct because my `.bib` file has dates.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mwerefs.bib}

@MISC{MacLachlan2006,
author = {{MacLachlan}, Anne J.},
title = {Developing graduate students of color for the professoriate in Science,
Technology, Engineering and Mathematics {(STEM)}},
year = {2006},
owner = {Ricardo Gomez},
publisher = {University of California, Berkeley, Center for Studies in Higher
Education},
timestamp = {2013.04.27}
}
@TECHREPORT{George2001,
author = {George, Y. S. and Neale, D. S. and Horne, V. V. and Malcolm, S. M.},
title = {In pursuit of a diverse science, technology, engineering, and mathematics
workforce: Recommended research priorities to enhance participation
by underrepresented minorities},
institution = {American Society for Advancement of Science {(AAAS)}},
year = {2001},
address = {Washington, {DC}},
owner = {Ricardo Gomez},
timestamp = {2013.04.27},
url = {http://ehrweb.aaas.org/mge/ Reports/Report1/AGEP/AGEP_report.pdf}
}
@ARTICLE{Dubin2000,
author = {Dubin, Jon C.},
title = {Faculty diversity as a clinical legal education imperative},
journal = {Hastings Law Journal},
year = {2000},
volume = {51},
pages = {445--478},
number = {3},
owner = {Ricardo Gomez},
timestamp = {2013.04.27}
}
@ARTICLE{Alger1999,
author = {Alger, Jonathan},
title = {When Color-Blind is Color-Bland: Ensuring Faculty Diversity in Higher
Education},
journal = {Stanford Law and Policy Review},
year = {1999},
volume = {10},
pages = {191--204},
number = {2},
owner = {Ricardo Gomez},
timestamp = {2013.04.27}
}
@ARTICLE{Carrell2010,
author = {Carrell, Scott E. and Page, Marianne E. and West, James E.},
title = {Sex and Science: How Professor Gender Perpetuates the Gender Gap},
journal = {The Quarterly Journal of Economics},
year = {2010},
volume = {125},
pages = {1101--1144},
number = {3}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, doi=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
%\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwerefs.bib}

\begin{document}

Several policy mechanisms have been implemented to reduce social, ethnic, and gender disparities in STEM education, including scholarships or loans for promising students, and alternative admission policies. A more recent policy mechanism, however, seeks to develop a pool of suitable individuals from traditionally underrepresented groups in STEM who can become faculty and mentors. This approach---known as the Alliance for Graduate Education and the Professoriate (AGEP)---resonates with research and anecdotal evidence that suggests that faculty who share the same background as their students can serve as effective role models \parencite{Carrell2010} since they are in a better position to understand their needs, expectations, and challenges, and this, in turn, can translate to higher enrollment and retention rates, and better race relations on campus \parencite{Alger1999, Dubin2000, George2001, MacLachlan2006}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You probably have compiled the document prior to updating biblatex (that's what the warning implies). Perhaps you should try to delete the biblatex control file (the `.bcf` file) and recompile your document.

Comment: From the first `\parencite{Carrell2010}` I get "(Carrell, Page, & West, 2010)"

Comment: I don't. That's why I'm posting the issue. I get "(Carrell, Page, & West, n.d)"

Comment: I reinstalled biber and biblatex and I can see dates now.

Answer (score 0):

*Important test* could be `style=authoryear`

try this

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

and see if it works. That should definitely work. Unfortunately, it is a different type of citation and you obviously would like to have APA and not humanities-style citations. The reason I suggest this is because you can use it as a test on your system. If it fails to produce an output with years, then it is likely that your typesetting system has a problem.

egreg's comment of \parentcite is correct + henriques recompiling suggestion.

---

FYI, I just typeset the original code provided in your post and I saw dates, not n.d. (no date)

**Order of commands**:

1. xelatex
2. bibtex
3. xelatex
4. xelatex

[image: orig code with dates]